# My rep has a wobble?

Tags: support, reputation

All through today and yesterday, my rep in SO has being going up and down by one compared to my actual rep. It's pretty weird, it never gets more than one off, but it seems like someone's undownvoting then downvoting one of my questions. However, it's not showing up in my detailed rep page: it's just randomly happening. I'm not sure if this is a wider problem, but if it's affecting me (with 6K rep) I don't know how much big rep wobble people like Jon Skeet have. I'm not sure though, it might just be someone that's not sure if a post of mine is good or bad. Any help?

Comment: Have you checked *show deleted posts* at the bottom of the rep page?

Comment: @juergend Tried that, no difference. No rep changes today that may have affected this.

Comment: If at the age of 92 only your rep has a wobble, you're doing quite fine. :p Then again, there have been users who scripted a bit of a fun bot which plays with up and down votes for a period. Perhaps that's at play?

Comment: There are some bugs in the way the rep counter in the top bar is managed; I see inconsistencies when downvoted after hitting the rep cap, then gaining another vote that compensates that downvote, for example.

Comment: perhaps, it is a rep-quake

Comment: +1 and -1 means it's not upvote and unupvote as those will cause +5/+10 and -5/-10 depending what has been voted. Maybe it's an answer you downvoted and its author is playing around by repeatedly deleting (giving you +1) then undeleting again (-1 again), actions that don't cause a bump and are hard to track down. Try going through the answers you recently downvoted and look in their revisions to see if that's really the case. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks!

Comment: I think a pinball analogy would work well here, because tilt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twice in the last two days, you've been returned 1 rep due to posts you've down voted being removed by their respective owners. Both were removed within ~15 minutes of your down vote. I'm pretty sure you *should* see a +1 for both on your [reputation page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1822164/itsnotalie?tab=reputation).

I looked at the recent votes cast in your direction, there's nothing to indicate that someone has found an ingenious new way to annoy you by randomly down voting one of your posts and then removing it. And if they had, you would (at least initially, before the grace period ran out) see what post was down voted.

The last down vote you received was 11 hours ago, and it was not retracted.

Comment: Oh well, so let's blame the cache. <sight> :)

Comment: _Always_ be Batman, and _always_ blame the cache.